# IF function in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a function in a cell to say: 
Blank if Tab 1 A2 cell is blank and Tab 2 A2 is blank. 
If Tab 1 A2 isn't blank and Tab 2 is blank the cell says "Pending" and if Tab 1 A2 isn't blank and Tab 2 A2 isn't blank then the cell = Tab 2 A2.

I'm working on a Google Sheets that need to reference other cells across 2 tabs.

Here's the function I have at the moment:

```
=IF(A13<>""&'Import Processing'!A13<>"",'Import Processing'!A13,IF(A13<>"","Pending"))"))
```

At the moment it's just showing whatever is in Tab 2 A2, and not regarding if Tab 1 A2 is blank or not.

Comment: What is your definition of blank. Truly empty? Or ""?

Comment: Also you are using & wrong. You looking for `AND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment, you are looking for the `AND` logical operator. Instead of `&` you could use it like so:

```
=IF(AND(A2="",Sheet2!A2=""),"",IF(Sheet2!A2="","Pending",Sheet2!A2))
```

***Note:*** You forgot to mention what happens when A2 is empty but Sheet2!A2 has a value. I took it that it A) wouldn't occur, and B) if it does occur, takes value from Sheet2!A2.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
=IF(('sheet1'!A2= "")*('sheet2'!A2= ""),, 
 IF(('sheet1'!A2<>"")*('sheet2'!A2= ""), "Pending", 
 IF(('sheet1'!A2<>"")*('sheet2'!A2<>""), 'sheet2'!A2, )))
```